# How do I use regular expressions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I don't know how to implement regular expressions in Ruby. I tried this code, but it always returns `true`:

```
firstName = "Stepen123"
res = Validation_firstName(firstName)
puts res

def  Validation_firstName(firstName)
   reg = /[a-zA-z][^0-9]/
if reg.match(firstName)
   return true 
else
   return false
 end
 end
```

I am not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Your regex matches a single letter followed by something that is not a digit, so it matched the beginning of your string, specifically "St".  What are you _trying_ to match, anyway?

Comment: Go to  http://rubular.com/r/59cqVn4YPs and use it to see how your pattern works.

Comment: thank you, i have to match if firstName should have only "Stepen" not "Stepen123", simply "Stepen" returns true, "stepen123" returns false

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite your method like this:

```
def validation_firstname(first_name)
  !!first_name[/^[a-z]+$/i]
end
```

Comment: really thankYou its working, i have tried /^[a-zA-Z]$/ this. i havent put "+". whats the meaning for this "+"

Comment: @God: It means "one or more." So one or more characters in the set `[a-zA-Z]`. Without that, it will only match one-character strings.

Comment: That is going to be for you to figure out. There are all sorts of regular expression tutorials on the internet, along with the cheat-sheet at the bottom of the page at Rubular.com. I'll just say that without it your code won't work and you should use what I gave in my example, rather than leave out things you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
def validation_firstname(first_name)
  first_name.scan(/\d+/).empty?
end

p validation_firstname("Stepen123") #=> false
p validation_firstname("Stepen") #=> true
```

Comment: This will return true for the input `" "`, which I don't think is desired.